# Error while setting up a new smb share using powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, smb

I'm working on writing a PowerShell script that will setup a folder structure on the c drive and then turn those folders into shares.

When using the `New-SmbShare` cmdlet I'm getting a 1332 or a 50 error.

With the Domain I get a 1332 Error

`New-SmbShare -Name "InstallerFiles" -Path "C:\SoftwareDistribution\InstallerFiles" -ContinuouslyAvailable $true -ReadAccess "domain\Authenticated Users"`

```
New-SmbShare : No mapping between account names and security IDs was done. 
At line:1 char:1
+ New-SmbShare -Name "InstallerFiles" -Path "C:\SoftwareDistribution\InstallerFile ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (MSFT_SMBShare:ROOT/Microsoft/Windows/SMB/MSFT_SMBShare) [New-SmbShare], CimException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Windows System Error 1332,New-SmbShare
```

If I remove the domain I get the 50 Error.

`New-SmbShare -Name "InstallerFiles" -Path "C:\SoftwareDistribution\InstallerFiles" -ContinuouslyAvailable $true -ReadAccess "Authenticated Users"`

```
New-SmbShare : The request is not supported. 
At line:1 char:1
+ New-SmbShare -Name "InstallerFiles" -Path "C:\SoftwareDistribution\InstallerFile ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (MSFT_SMBShare:ROOT/Microsoft/Windows/SMB/MSFT_SMBShare) [New-SmbShare], CimException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Windows System Error 50,New-SmbShare
```

I'm able to create the Share if I remove `-ContinuouslyAvailable` and `-ReadAccess`, but I want to be able to assign the users or security groups permissions from the script.

What do I need to change in order to setup an smb share and assign users or security groups using PowerShell?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to remove the `-ContinuouslyAvailable` flag. As far as I know, this flag is set to True by default anyway.

You may also want to take a look at these:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/0666a96f-d8c9-4a20-b994-10a003cd7047/big-performance-isssue-cafs-and-10-gbe-network?forum=winserverfiles

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/davguents_blog/2012/10/21/windows-server-2012-continuous-availability-file-server-feature/

As the function may not be available in your environment, hence the `New-SmbShare : The request is not supported.` Error

and your first error: `No mapping between account names and security IDs was done`, i believe this basically means "user not found" see here:

http://www.rebeladmin.com/2016/01/how-to-fix-error-no-mapping-between-account-names-and-security-ids-in-active-directory/

and maybe try the example from here:

https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/134715/new-smbshare-no-mapping-between-account-names-and-security-ids-was-done

Comment: Thank you for the help, removing `-ContinuouslyAvailable` fix the errors.

Comment: `-ContinuouslyAvailable` is `$false` by default.  It's for use in clustered situations.

Answer (score 0):

Combining the answers here:

```
New-SmbShare -Name "InstallerFiles" `
 -Path "C:\SoftwareDistribution\InstallerFiles" `
 -ReadAccess "Authenticated Users"
```